# "Failed to resolve module specifier" or "window is not defined" when I import WASM in JS worker

Tags: javascript, rust, web-worker, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to import my WASM library (written in Rust) inside a JS worker. And I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'mylib'
```

Or if I try to use `worker-loader` the error is different, but in the same line:

```
window is not defined
```

**What is the nature of the errors and how am I supposed to fix it?**

The details are represented below. I tried to make the example as minimal as possible (without `worker-loader`).

---

The structure of my project is:

```
wasm-worker-example/
    mylib/
        pkg/*
        src/
            lib.rs
        Cargo.toml
    www/
        bundles/*
        node_modules/*
        index.html
        index.js
        my.worker.js
        package.js
        webpack.config.js
```

lib.rs

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn concat(a: &str, b: &str) -> String {
    a.to_string() + b
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "mylib"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Alexander <mail@fomalhaut.su>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "www",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mylib": "file:../mylib/pkg",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './index',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./bundles/'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: "/bundles/"
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="bundles/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
import("mylib").then(wasm => {
    // It works fine
    console.log(wasm.concat("qwe", "rty"));

    var worker = new Worker("my.worker.js");
    worker.postMessage('Message to worker');
});
```

my.worker.js

```js
// Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'mylib'
import("mylib").then(wasm => {
    // Not reached
    console.log(wasm.concat("qwe", "rty"));

    self.addEventListener('message', e => {
        console.log(e.data);
    });
});
```

---

I prepare `mylib` with (in `mylib`):

```
wasm-pack build
```

For frontend (in `www`):

```
npm install
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

To run (in `www`):

```
http-server
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader might help

Comment: @Kaiido I have tried `worker-loader`. It gives a different error in the same import: `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Something is expecting to run in a Window context not in a worker. You could try to spoof it `self.window = self` at the top of your worker script (before the imports) but probably they are trying to access things that may not be accessible in the Worker context.

Comment: It didn't help, unfortunately. Same error.